# Android crop image in byte array before text recognition

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, google-mlkit, image-cropper

I have a text recognition app and I only want the app to read text within a certain box on my screen. My approach is to crop **AN image from my camera** before I send it to text recognition. I am having an issue cropping my image first.

If I try to convert the byte to a bitmap then crop it using -

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
Bitmap resizedbitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 100, 100, 200, 200);
```

and then use create bitmap to create a new bitmap that is cropped with a RECT - but since it is null it is failing.

I am receiving null for the bitmap - I have tried changing the options, I have added read write permissions to the manifest - but it is still coming up null.

I am now trying to convert the byte array to a yuvimage but I think data is being lost in the compression so when I scan my image - the text recognition is giving me distorted text blocks and it is not very accurate.

```
        int correctRotation = RNCameraViewHelper.getCorrectCameraRotation(rotation, getFacing(),
            getCameraOrientation());
        
        if (data.length < (1.5 * width * height)) {
          return;
        }

        if (willCallTextTask) {
          textRecognizerTaskLock = true;
          TextRecognizerAsyncTaskDelegate delegate = (TextRecognizerAsyncTaskDelegate) cameraView;
      
          final byte[] compressedImage;
          final YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);
          final ByteArrayOutputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          Log.d("Tag", "Image Stream" + getWidth());
          Log.d("Tag", "WIDTH" + width);
          Log.d("Tag", "HEIGHT" + height);
          yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 100, imageStream);
          compressedImage = imageStream.toByteArray();
          new TextRecognizerAsyncTask(delegate, mThemedReactContext, compressedImage, width, height, correctRotation,
              getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density, getFacing(), getWidth(), getHeight(), mPaddingX, mPaddingY)
                  .execute();
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Any suggestions would be great - or if theres a better way to do this that would be amazing!

Comment: `My approach is to crop a local image from my camera before I send it to text recognition. ` Well ok. But i do not understand what that would have to do with a local region on your screen. We suppose that the local image contains the text.

Comment: The issue is the text recognition is returning the first text it sees and then stopping. The item we are scanning is a coupon and the text we need to return is not the only text on the coupon. Also if the user is scanning the coupon next to another piece of paper or anything with text on it - the recognition is returning the first text block. So the necessity to crop the image is to make sure the only data going to the text recognizer is the area of the coupon that contains the specific text we need and remove all the other text.

Comment: Ok. But i still see in your post: `My approach is to crop a local image..` and i dont understand how that matches with what you just told.

Comment: Cropping an image from my camera preview. Not one from a url or another storage device. Sorry if I misspoke - I mean not an image from another location.